# How to show that $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|a_n| = lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I'd like to ask if this equality is true: $$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|a_n| = lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n|$$
It seems to me to be correct, but I do not know how to prove it.

**Edit**: I see that it is not true in every case, but it must be true if the series converges, why is it so?

Comment: What if $a_n=1$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true, a counter example is
$$
a_n=\frac1n,\qquad \lim_{n\to \infty}|a_n|=0, \qquad \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|a_n|=\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac1n=\infty.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, somehow I did not think about this basic example...

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga You are welcome.

Comment: Could you see my new edit?

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga OK, if the series $\lim_{n \to  \infty}\sum_{k=0}^N |a_n|=S<\infty$ then using $|a_N|=S_N-S_{N-1}$ we have $\lim_{N \to  \infty}|a_N|=\lim_{N \to  \infty}S_N-\lim_{N \to  \infty}S_{N-1}=S-S=0$. But we also have $\lim_{N \to  \infty}\sum_{n=N}^\infty |a_n|=S-\lim_{N \to  \infty}S_N=0$. Then you get the desired equality.

Comment: Why $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |a_n| = S - \lim_{N\to \infty} S_N$?

Comment: We have $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |a_n| = S - S_{N-1} $ right?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand why is that.

Comment: You have $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |a_n| =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n| -\sum_0^{N-1}|a_n| = S - S_{N-1}$ right?

Comment: Ohhh you're right now I get it, thank you it is perfectly clear!

Answer (score 1):

It is true if either

a) $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges, by virtue of the fact that both quantities are zero, or

b) $|a_n| \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you, but why is a) true?